# 2D pattern search algorithms

Tags: javascript, algorithm, pattern-matching

I need to learn about 2D pattern searching algorithms. Tips and links greatly appreciated.

More to the point:

Given a matrix of M[m,n] with values in K
example

000000000000
000001000000
010`1`00010010 = M, K = {0, 1}
010`1`00010001
101`11`1010111

and a matrix L[i, j] with values in K + {X} representing a "shape"
example, the shape of letter "L"

`1`X
`1`X = L
`11`

What algoritms can answer to the following questions:

1. Can L be found in M ?
2. How many times L can be found in M (disjunctive L's, no common pieces (1's or 0's))
3. How many times L can be found in M (can have common pieces (1's or 0's))
4. How many times L, and K (K is defined similarly like L, K != L) can be found in M (disjoint)
   etc.

The language of implementation is to be JavaScript, but any other will do.

EDIT
Also found [this PDF](https://web.archive.org/web/20150621110055/http://www.fastar.org/publications/MScMartijn.pdf).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this [presentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20150621110105/http://www.fastar.org/publications/MScPresentationMartijn.ppt) it should give you a basic knowledge.

The X symbol can be treated like wildcard so it will always give a match.

Don't know what exactly you mean by

> How many times L, and K (K is defined like L) can be found in M (disjoint) etc.

K stands for alphabet or shape (like L)?

Problem of determining maximum number of disjoint matches will be harder. The approach would be following:

- find all possible matches
- create graph where node represents matches and edge represents that two matches have common field.
- now you have to find maximum independent set in this graph ([wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_%28graph_theory%29)) - set of vertices in a graph, no two of which are adjacent so problem constraints are not violated.

EDIT: If your shape is L the match can be computed efficently. Create tables for columns and rows and for each cell check if there is a match upwards and to the right.

Comment: Shape like L but K can be != L (not necessarily the same shape)

Comment: Does L shape always fits int grid of size 2x3? If so some optimizations can be applied.

Comment: What about alphabet is it always {0,1}?

Comment: For the sake of simplicity, yes. The {X} set is just a placeholder to define shapes. My shape is not just L, it is used as an example, I am looking for a general aproach.

Comment: @clyfe why is this answer accepted? Unless I missed something, the linked presentation doesn't even mention matching patterns than contain wildcards, like you asked. I understand the answer is likely "this was 13 years ago, I've no idea", but still.