# Non exact pattern search algorithm in 2d integer array

Tags: java, algorithm, pattern-matching

Is there any algorithm that search a pattern with some 0s in a target array which any number on 0s in the pattern does not affect determining the result?

This question is similiar to [2D pattern search algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466370/2d-pattern-search-algorithms) but the links provided are not accessible.

Given a m*n array T and u*v array P, u ≤ m, v ≤ n, 0 ≤ P[i][j] < q, where q is a positive integer.
0s in P can be an arbirtary integer in T if P lies in T. For example:

```
q = 10
P[3][3] = {{2, 3, 0},
           {0, 1, 5}
            9, 0, 2}}
T[5][5] = {{2, 3, 4, 3, 6},
           {4, 1, 5, 7, 8},
           {9, 1, 2, 3, 1},
           {2, 4, 5, 1, 5},
           {3, 1, 9, 0, 2}}
```

The algorithm that I'm seeking should give (0,0) and (2,2) since the pattern is found and any number in T lies on 0 in P does not affect the output.

I've come across Rabin-Karp algorithm but the 0s are taken into account.

Implementation in Java would be great. Other languages will also do.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: hello and welcome to SO, Please read the guide how to ask questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: By the way, if you can access the Internet Archive the presentation has been archived [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150621110105/fastar.org/publications/MScPresentationMartijn.ppt)

Comment: So a 0 in P is essentially a "don't care"? Like an asterisk (*) in a regular expression, it'll match any digit?

Comment: @JimMischel Yes, any integer in T will do.

Comment: What's wrong with the obvious naive algorithm? Yes, I could shave a few steps off of that one, but the overhead of the necessary logic probably exceeds the performance win.

Comment: @btilly Time complexity of the naive algorithm might be m\*n\*u\*v in this scenario (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/22546663/15999807). This would be very slow if u = m, v = n.

Comment: Unless some value is very common, average time is only `O(m*n)`. Don't optimize prematurely.

Comment: I've updated the Q & A in the question you linked (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466370/2d-pattern-search-algorithms) to fix the broken links. Does it answer your question now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure of this problem resembles 2D convolution: a kernel is applied at every possible position to a 2D array, some value is calculated based on corresponding elements (equality) and these values are further processed (filtering out incomplete matches). And 2D convolution indeed gives a solution to this problem in [image: O(n * m * log(n * m))] time for any input. (this complexity is a simplification reasonable in practice, more in the last section)

### Reduction to bivariate polynomial multiplication over [image: Z/p]

Let's define polynomials describing the array to be searched in and the pattern:

[image: T(x, y) = Σ T[i][j] x^i y^j]

[image: P(x, y) = Σ P[u-i-1][v-j-1] x^i y^j]

`P[][]` is essentially rotated 180°. Their product is:

[image: M(x, y) = Σ T[i][j] P[u-i-1][v-j-1] x^(i+k) y^(j+l)]

What is the coefficient of [image: x^(u-1) y^(v-1)] equal to? It's a sum of `u * v` products between `P[][]` and `T[][]` elements, where `T[i][j]` is multiplied with `P[i][j]` with `0 <= i < u`, `0 <= j < v`.

Similarly for all `0 <= k <= m - u`, `0 <= l <= n - v`, the coefficient of [image: x^(u-1+i) y^(v-1+i)] is equal to the sum of `u * v` products of `T[][]` and `P[][]` elements where `T[i+k][j+l]` is multiplied with `P[i][j]` with `0 <= i < u`, `0 <= j < v`.

For other `k`, `l` we have sums of products for incomplete overlaps that we don't care about.

If `T[][]` matches `P[][]` at some position, we know exactly what the corresponding coefficient will be: it's a sum of squares of `P[][]` elements, since all non-zero elements have to match others equal to them and it doesn't matter what were zeros matched to. Converse is, of course, not guaranteed: if some coefficient is equal to this value, it might not correspond to a match. Let's ignore this for now, at least we can expect to reduce the number of positions to verify matches at.

For implementation purposes, this convolution can be done over [image: Z/p] instead of [image: N]: all coefficients will be calculated modulo prime number significantly greater than `m * n` (and greater than `q`, but we will eliminate this restriction later).

### Implementing bivariate polynomial multiplication

There's a standard trick to reduce multidimensional convolution to 1D — helix transform, in other words index projection. In our case we will map [image: x^i y^j] to [image: t^(i*(n+v-1)) + j)]. Then after performing 1D convolution, the inner index `j` will not overflow into the outer index and can be separated.

The algorithm for performing 1D convolution over [image: Z/p] is based on the Number Theoretic Transform, almost identical to the more popular Fast Fourier Transform, except instead of a primitive root of unity in complex numbers a primitive root modulo `p` is used.

### Increasing robustness

Our current algorithm may generate false positives when sum of products just happens to be equal to what we expect modulo `p`, and in theory values in `T[][]` and `P[][]` can be such that this effect becomes disastrous. Let's remap these values to others, random "keys" in `1..p-1`, keeping zeros in `P[][]` intact. The key for each distinct value will be sampled independently for `T[][]` and `P[][]`, different values can even happen to be mapped to the same key (with very low probability). This will simplify further analysis.

Such remapping reduces false positive rate per pattern position to `1 / p`, rigorously — to `2 / p` or less for every input. The sum of products at a position differs from the target sum by [image: Σ a_ij tkey_i pkey_j], where `a` counts the difference between the number of cells where `tkey_i` and `pkey_j` were matched and were supposed to be matched (making corresponding base values in `T[][]` and `P[][]` equal). If we vary any imperfectly matched `pkey_j` through `1..p-1`, the difference will vary through `p-1` distinct values, unless the sum of its multipliers, `a_ij * tkey_i`, is zero, which has probability slightly less than `1 / p` as a sum of independent variables.

### Obtaining results and detailed complexity

`p` can be taken sufficiently big to make the total false positive rate through all positions arbitrarily small, the Chinese Remainder Theorem can be used to combine results modulo different `p`. So it isn't strictly necessary to verify matches, giving the stated complexity, [image: O(n * m * log(n * m))], to obtain correct results with confidence level of, say, `(1 - 1e-38)^(n * m) ~= 1 - 1e-38 * n * m ~= 100%`.

Alternatively all probable matches can be verified, giving complexity [image: O(n * m * (log(n * m) + c))] where `c` is the amount of true matches, as long as [image: p >= max(u * v, (m - u) * (n - v) / (log(m * n) + c))] is maintained.

### C++ implementation

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

using Matrix = std::vector<std::vector<uint32_t>>;

namespace Impl {

template <uint32_t mod>
struct ModEnv {
  static constexpr uint32_t prod(uint32_t a, uint32_t b) {
    return uint64_t{a} * b % mod;
  }

  static constexpr uint32_t sum(uint32_t a, uint32_t b) {
    return a + b - (b >= mod - a ? mod : 0);
  }

  static constexpr uint32_t dif(uint32_t a, uint32_t b) {
    return a - b + (a < b ? mod : 0);
  }

  static constexpr uint32_t binpow(uint32_t x, uint32_t p) {
    uint32_t res = 1;
    while (p) {
      if (p % 2) {
        res = prod(res, x);
      }
      x = prod(x, x);
      p /= 2;
    }
    return res;
  }

  static void ntt(std::vector<uint32_t>& v, bool inverse) {
    constexpr uint32_t root = 5555;
    int n = v.size();
    for (int i = 1, j = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      int bit = n;
      do {
        bit /= 2;
        j ^= bit;
      } while (!(j & bit));
      if (i < j) {
        std::swap(v[i], v[j]);
      }
    }
    for (int len = 2; len <= n; len *= 2) {
      uint32_t d = mod / len;
      uint32_t pw = binpow(root, inverse ? mod - 1 - d : d);
      for (int i = 0; i < n; i += len) {
        int half = len / 2;
        uint32_t w = 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < half; ++j) {
          uint32_t s = v[i + j], t = prod(v[i + j + half], w);
          v[i + j] = sum(s, t);
          v[i + j + half] = dif(s, t);
          w = prod(w, pw);
        }
      }
    }
    if (inverse) {
      uint32_t inv = binpow(n, mod - 2);
      for (uint32_t& x : v) {
        x = prod(x, inv);
      }
    }
  }

  static std::vector<uint32_t> conv1d(std::vector<uint32_t> a, std::vector<uint32_t> b) {
    int output_size = a.size() + b.size() - 1, pow2_size = 1;
    while (pow2_size < output_size) {
      pow2_size *= 2;
    }
    a.resize(pow2_size);
    b.resize(pow2_size);
    ntt(a, false);
    ntt(b, false);
    for (int i = 0; i < pow2_size; ++i) {
      a[i] = prod(a[i], b[i]);
    }
    ntt(a, true);
    a.resize(output_size);
    return a;
  }

  static Matrix conv2d_180(Matrix a, Matrix b) {
    int m = a.size(), n = a[0].size(), u = b.size(), v = b[0].size();
    int stride = n + v - 1;
    std::vector<uint32_t> b1d((u - 1) * stride + v);
    for (int i = 0; i < u; ++i) {
      assert(b[i].size() == v);
      copy(b[i].rbegin(), b[i].rend(), b1d.begin() + (u - i - 1) * stride);
    }
    Matrix{}.swap(b);
    std::vector<uint32_t> a1d((m - 1) * stride + n);
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
      copy(a[i].begin(), a[i].end(), a1d.begin() + i * stride);
    }
    Matrix{}.swap(a);
    auto res1d = conv1d(std::move(a1d), std::move(b1d));
    int s = m - u + 1, t = n - v + 1;
    Matrix res(s, std::vector<uint32_t>(t));
    for (int i = 0; i < s; ++i) {
      copy_n(res1d.begin() + (i + u - 1) * stride + v - 1, t, res[i].begin());
    }
    return res;
  }

  static std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> pattern_match(Matrix t, Matrix p) {
    std::unordered_map<uint32_t, uint32_t> t_map, p_map;
    std::mt19937 rng(std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(
        std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<uint32_t> d(1, mod - 1);
    for (auto& row: t) {
      for (uint32_t& val: row) {
        auto [it, f] = t_map.emplace(val, 0);
        if (f) {
          it->second = d(rng);
        }
        val = it->second;
      }
    }
    uint32_t expected_value = 0;
    for (auto& row: p) {
      for (uint32_t& val: row) {
        if (val == 0) {
          continue;
        }
        auto [it, f] = p_map.emplace(val, 0);
        if (f) {
          it->second = d(rng);
        }
        if (auto t_it = t_map.find(val); t_it != t_map.end()) {
          expected_value = sum(expected_value, prod(t_it->second, it->second));
        } else {
          // value in pattern doesn't exist in text
          return {};
        }
        val = it->second;
      }
    }
    auto conv = conv2d_180(std::move(t), std::move(p));
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> res;
    for (int i = 0; i < conv.size(); ++i) {
      for (int j = 0; j < conv[0].size(); ++j) {
        if (conv[i][j] == expected_value) {
          res.emplace_back(i, j);
        }
      }
    }
    return res;
  }
};

template <uint32_t mod>
bool can_use(const Matrix& t, const Matrix& p) {
  int m = t.size(), n = t[0].size(), u = p.size(), v = p[0].size();
  int stride = n + v - 1;
  int poly_size = (m - 1) * stride + n + (u - 1) * stride + v - 1, pow2_size = 1;
  while (pow2_size < poly_size) {
    pow2_size *= 2;
  }
  return (mod - 1 & 1 - mod) % pow2_size == 0;
}

void verify_matrix(const Matrix& m) {
  assert(!m.empty() && !m[0].empty() && m.size() * m[0].size() < 1 << 30);
  for (int i = 1; i < m.size(); ++i) {
    assert(m[i].size() == m[0].size());
  }
}

void verify_text_pattern(const Matrix& t, const Matrix& p) {
  verify_matrix(t);
  verify_matrix(p);
  assert(t.size() >= p.size() && t[0].size() >= p[0].size());
}

constexpr uint32_t mod1 = (3 << 30) + 1, mod2 = (13 << 28) + 1;

}  // namespace Impl

std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> pattern_match_single_mod(Matrix t, Matrix p) {
  Impl::verify_text_pattern(t, p);
  if (Impl::can_use<Impl::mod2>(t, p)) {
    return Impl::ModEnv<Impl::mod2>::pattern_match(std::move(t), std::move(p));
  }
  assert(Impl::can_use<Impl::mod1>(t, p) && "text and pattern sizes are too big");
  return Impl::ModEnv<Impl::mod1>::pattern_match(std::move(t), std::move(p));
}

std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> pattern_match_two_mods(Matrix t, Matrix p) {
  Impl::verify_text_pattern(t, p);
  assert(Impl::can_use<Impl::mod2>(t, p) && "text and pattern sizes are too big");
  auto m1 = Impl::ModEnv<Impl::mod1>::pattern_match(t, p);
  auto m2 = Impl::ModEnv<Impl::mod2>::pattern_match(std::move(t), std::move(p));
  std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> m(m1.size() + m2.size());
  m.erase(set_intersection(m1.begin(), m1.end(), m2.begin(), m2.end(), m.begin()), m.end());
  return m;
}

std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> pattern_match_naive(const Matrix& t, const Matrix& p) {
  std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> res;
  for (int i = 0; i < t.size() - p.size() + 1; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < t[0].size() - p[0].size() + 1; ++j) {
      bool ok = 1;
      for (int k = 0; k < p.size() && ok; ++k) {
        for (int l = 0; l < p[0].size() && ok; ++l) {
          ok &= p[k][l] == 0 || p[k][l] == t[i + k][j + l];
        }
      }
      if (ok) {
        res.emplace_back(i, j);
      }
    }
  }
  return res;
}

void stress(int m, int n, int u, int v, double q, double prob_zero) {
  std::mt19937 rng(std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(
      std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count());
  std::uniform_real_distribution<double> du(1, q);
  std::bernoulli_distribution db(prob_zero);
  while (1) {
    Matrix t(m, std::vector<uint32_t>(n));
    Matrix p(u, std::vector<uint32_t>(v));
    for (auto& row: t) {
      for (auto& elem: row) {
        elem = du(rng);
      }
    }
    for (auto& row: p) {
      for (auto& elem: row) {
        elem = db(rng) ? 0 : du(rng);
      }
    }
    int i = rng() % (m - u + 1), j = rng() % (n - v + 1);
    for (int k = 0; k < u; ++k) {
      for (int l = 0; l < v; ++l) {
        if (p[k][l] != 0) {
          t[i + k][j + l] = p[k][l];
        }
      }
    }
    auto naive = pattern_match_naive(t, p);
    assert(naive == pattern_match_single_mod(std::move(t), std::move(p)));
  }
}

int main() {
  auto ans = pattern_match_two_mods(
    {{2, 3, 4, 3, 6},
     {4, 1, 5, 7, 8},
     {9, 1, 2, 3, 1},
     {2, 4, 5, 1, 5},
     {3, 1, 9, 0, 2}},
    {{2, 3, 0},
     {0, 1, 5},
     {9, 0, 2}}
  );
  for (auto [i, j]: ans) {
    std::cout << '(' << i << ", " << j << ") ";
  }
  std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Nice algorithms answer. Let me see if I can decypher this into java.

Comment: I can't seem to get the projection right, can you add some implementation details?

Comment: Thanks, @alvonellos! I'm not sure what could've gone wrong with index projection, I'll add a reference implementation in C++ later.

Comment: @alvonellos Done. If something is unclear, let me know.

Comment: you are a much stronger coder than I. I'm a little stuck. Can we link up somehow? Hope you are well.

Comment: @maxplus Is it necessary to pad 0s to every row in T and P before NTT? Why not just pad enough 0s to P so that it has dimension `u` by `n`?